# MacBook Pro (2006, A1150) fails to boot

Tags: hardware, startup

My MacBook Pro (2006, model A1150) fails to boot beyond the white screen AFTER the screen with the Apple logo and spinner.

I have tried:
Resetting PRAM     (doesn't work)
Resetting SMC     (how can you tell?)
Apple Hardware Test     (says no problems)
Swapping RAM chips with a similar machine     (no effect)
Re-installing OS 10.6.3.     (Seems to be O.K.)
Booting in "Verbose Mode"     (Stops at `"Unable to read Block 16 17 18 19"` etc)
 
Booting in "Target mode"     (this works!)
Booting in "Safe mode"     (this works too!)

What is preventing it from booting, and how can I resolve this matter?

Comment: Thanks for that.  Yes, I did indeed erase the HD before installation.

Answer (score 1):

When you re-installed the OS, did you erase or repartition the hard drive? The Apple hardware test never found a hardware problem I had with my MacPro so it is not necessarily comprehensive.

The Verbose message sounds like a "can't read the hard drive at block...." message. Which would mean a damaged hard drive.

There appears to be some part of the OS that is stored on the hard drive at a particular place that can't be read at boot time. This part appears to be bypassed in safe mode and target mode.

Good luck!